# Angular 6 - API Post call in Service - Change to use XML

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 6 and I have a Service which does a Json post call.

Here is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  create(userId, title, body) {
      const postedData = { userid: 1, title: title, body: body };
      return this.http.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', postedData, httpOptions).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
      }, error => console.log('There was an error: '));
  }

}
```

My Question is: How can I change this so I can post XML instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the encoding type in the headers of your post request `'Content-Type': 'text/xml';`

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' })
};
```

Comment: So does the postedData not have to change format? const postedData = { userid: 1, title: title, body: body };

Comment: No, you don't have to change the postedData format. It will be done automatically as long as you use the correct encoding type. I edited my answer